# Sumprod evaluate gives name vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Sumproduct function in vba.
First i tried this :

```
   sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 6) = Application.SUMPRODUCT((Transaction = "Vente") * (TickerD2 = sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2)), ValeurFlux))
```

Where Transaction,TickerD2 and ValeurFlux are ranges of the same lenght.(it's an entire column).
I've seen in many forums that sumproduct in vba is problematic when there are criterias.

People suggest to use .Evaluate

```
   sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 6) = Application.Evaluate("SOMMEPROD((Transaction = "Vente") * (TickerD2 = sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2)), ValeurFlux)")
```

But it gives name.
I use SOMMEPROD because my Excel is in French so i think i need to translate.
I think there is a typo error in the formula but im not familiar with evaluate.

Thank you.

---

This is the formula i use in excel and it works! 
I don't know why in vba it can't

```
   =SOMMEPROD((Data2!D:D="Achat")*(Data2!C:C=B8);Data2!I:I)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main problems I saw were that you have to double up quotes when used within a quoted string and you needed the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) of `sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2)`, not the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) itself.

```
  Dim sumproductFormula As String

  sumproductFormula = "SUMPRODUCT((Transaction=""Vente"")*" & _
                               "(TickerD2=" & sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2).Address & ")," & _
                                "ValeurFlux)"
  sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 6) = Application.Evaluate(sumproductFormula)
```

I find it easier to build a long string in pieces assigned to a string type var and just use the var in the [Application Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx).

Comment: TickerD2, transaction and valeurflux are ranges in another sheet. I try to insert TickerD2.Address in the formula but it doesn't work because it's just giving me $D:$D (without the sheet to locate it)

Comment: Use `TickerD2.Address(external:=true)` to get the full path and worksheet name. It is OK to give too much information like the full path but never OK not to give enough.

Comment: btw, you really shouldn't be using full column references in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff). There are ways to cut the ranges down to the minimum required with dynamic named ranges.

Comment: This works for my test: `    prod = "=SUMPRODUCT((Transaction=""Vente"")*" & _
                       "(TickerD2=" & sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2).Address(external:=True) & ")," & _
                        "ValeurFlux)"` . Put a `debug.print prod` directly underneath it. Also remember that VBA is very EN-US centric. I'm pretty sure that formulas have to be in EN-US language, not FR-FR but I am not 100% sure about application.evaluate.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((Transaction.Address(external:=True)="Achat")*(TickerD2.Address(external:=True)=ARGENT),ValeurFlux.Address(external:=True)) 
This is the degub print i get. There is still an error

Comment: That is not even close to what I just supplied.

Comment: Because the formula sumprod is in the same sheet than sht.Cells.
The external values (TickerD2,Transaction and ValeurFlux are in the page Data2  which is external?

Comment: A named range with workbook scope does not need a sheet name in a formula.

Comment: It says error 2029

=SUMPRODUCT((Transaction="Achat")*(TickerD2='[Performance titres_Bencou.xlsx]ARGENT'!$B$8),ValeurFlux)

Comment: Well, it looks like that is close to working. See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823604) or maybe [this](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/823604). What worksheet are these named ranges on?

Comment: I would recommend that you try it with actual worksheet addresses. At least then you can make sure that the formula is correct. I'm afraid that there isn't much more I can do without having a redacted copy of the workbook for full testing.

Comment: In EN-US as `prod = "=SUMPRODUCT((Data2!D:D=""Achat"")*(Data2!C:C=B8), Data2!I:I)"`.